# manipulate 2d gaussian in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, gaussian, gaussianblur

I wish to plot 2d gaussian in matlab, and here is the code and generated graph.

```
x=0:.02:1; y=x; 
r = 0.2; %set standard deviation
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y); 
Z=exp(-((X-0.5).^2+(Y-0.5).^2)/(2*r^2)); 
mesh(X,Y,Z) 
colormap([0 0 0]);
```

[image]

Since we can get a 2d gaussian from multipying two 1d gaussian:
[image]

I wish to do the same thing to "Z" in my code:

```
x=0:.02:1; y=x; 
r = 0.2; %set standard deviation
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y); 
Z=exp(-((X-0.5).^2)/(2*r^2)) * exp(-((Y-0.5).^2)/(2*r^2)); 
mesh(X,Y,Z) 
colormap([0 0 0]);
```

But here is what I got: a flat plane
[image]

I do not really understand why. Could someone shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to multiply the x and y portions with `.*` instead of `*` perhaps?

Comment: Also, you can skip the `meshgrid` call. Instead do `X=0:.02:1; Y=X.';`.

Comment: Thank you, @MadPhysicist, indeed I forget to multiply element wise!

Comment: You could close this as a typo.